# Save output image from layout on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-sdcard

i want to save output image from layout[redline], 
[image]

the program, take image picture from camera -> save in sdcard -> load image gray and original to layout. i want to save gray and original image became one image like on the red line.

```
public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String    TAG = "Saliency";
    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ImageView mImageView2;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
    private View view;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;

    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }


    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (! storageDir.exists()){
                        Log.d("ImageDataset", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Mat mInput = new Mat();
        mInput = Highgui.imread(mCurrentPhotoPath, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat mRgba = new Mat(mInput.rows()/4, mInput.cols()/4, CvType.CV_64FC1);
        Imgproc.resize(mInput, mInput, mRgba.size());

        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mInput.cols(),  mInput.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);     
        Utils.matToBitmap(mInput, resultBitmap); 
        //  
        Bitmap ImageAsli= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Bitmap ImageAsliResize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ImageAsli, ImageAsli.getWidth(), ImageAsli.getHeight(), false);

        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
        mImageView2.setImageBitmap(ImageAsliResize);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch(actionCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;          
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = 
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
        }
    };


    private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                    // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
;
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        mImageBitmap = null;

        Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntend);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
                picBtn, 
                mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        );



        //minimal versi froyo
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                handleBigCameraPhoto();
            }
            break;
        } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B

        } // switch
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
    }

    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            Button btn, 
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
            String intentName
    ) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);            
        } else {
            btn.setText( 
                getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a "screenshot" of any view (including your parent layout) by temporarily enabling the drawing cache on it with [`setDrawingCacheEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) and then calling [`getDrawingCache()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) to retrieve a Bitmap of the view. Don't forget to disable the drawing cache after saving the image to improve performance. Save the bitmap to disk using the `Bitmap.compress()` method.

However please note that the size of your bitmap image will then depend on the size of the device screen. You can get more control by drawing your images directly to a Canvas backed by a mutable Bitmap instead of using a visible layout as source.